# Javascript JSON.parse or directly access

Tags: javascript

When we can read a property directly from string:

```
var data = {"id":1,"name":"abc","address":{"streetName":"cde","streetId":2}};
console.log(data.address.streetName); // cde
```

Why do people use `JSON.parse`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj.address.streetName); // cde
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a string, but Javascript object. String is given below

```
var data = '{"id":1,"name":"abc","address":{"streetName":"cde","streetId":2}}';
```

to make it object we use JSON.parse

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj.address.streetName); // cde
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, data is an object, but in your second example, data is a JSON **string**.

That's a major difference. You **could** call eval(data) to parse a JSON string, but that's very unsafe.

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.parse()` expects a string. More specifically, a string with a JSON-encoded piece of data.

If it's applied to an object then it's an error, the source of which is probably the common confusion that seems to exist between JavaScript objects and the JSON format.

Comment: Additionally, the keys inside strings passed to JSON.parse need to be properly quoted; otherwise, JSON.parse throws an exception